# Installing React app with yarn Plug n Play

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, yarnpkg

I want to make a react app with yarn using PnP(Plug and Play), so that I can install any dependencies without using node modules, so I type this in terminal:

```
yarn create react-app project-name --use-pnp
```

Then, the app has created, but when I start the server it says

```
    Failed to compile.

    ./src/App.js
    Module not found: You cannot require a package ("react-refresh") that is not declared in your dependencies (via "/home/path/path/path/path/project-name/src/App.js")
```

Then, when I install the "react-refresh" it gives me another error.
**Is it possible to create react app with PnP?**

Comment: is the issue solved? if yes how ?

Comment: @NRK nope I didn't solved it, it appears that they don't care about CRA(create react app) with pnp. My sugestion you should use tools like webpack with pnp good luck.

Comment: That is weird, i tried it with latest yarn version, yet it did not work, getting similar error. i dont know what i am missing

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it seems to be a Yarn issue with the v1.12, which version do you have and this link helped you?

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5255

Answer (score -2):

Currently i don't use yarn pnp, use pnpm instead if you want to save your storage.

```
npm i -g pnpm
```

pnpm will save your disk space out of the box.